# EXCEL VBA: Sort through years and find simple Average,Max,and Min by decade

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, filter, filtering

Alright so the scenario: I've got three columns that I'm currently working with. Column A is my UNIQUE ID, Column B is my YEAR, and Column C will be my VALUES. I'm working in excel, and have about 350,000 rows to work with so the problem/goal:

I'm trying to find the right code that will sift through the years and give me the AVERAGE, MAX, and MIN values for the VALUE Column C, by decade.

Again, I have hundreds of thousands of rows of code to work with, and I want to sort by decade from the 1940's to the 2010's; where for each decade it will give me the AVERAGE, MAX, and MIN values.

I'm only an amateur programmer, so of I know how to filter it decade by decade one by one, by creating multiple sorts over a long and tedious period of time. However, I'm wondering if anyone knows of code that can complete it all in one fell swoop thus saving the program the process of having to sift through my 350,000 rows of code more than once.

I will be extremely grateful to whomever can teach me this bit, good luck and you have my thanks!

EDIT:: (HOW THE AVERAGES, MAX, and MINS will be DISPLAYED))::

"Ah, I apologize for not clarifying that. I just assumed I would take care of that after they 'magically' appeared I guess, haha. Anyways, I will be displaying  the decade information that I sort out in a simple table in a new worksheet where AVERAGE, MAX, MIN, will be the three row titles and the decades will be the column titles for the table."

Comment: Where are the results supposed to be?  A new worksheet?  The same worksheet?  How do you plan on displaying the decades?

Comment: You can do this without VBA? Would you like a formula only solution? If so, tell me what version of XL you are running.

Comment: It would be neat to do this with an SQL statement with a "group by year" operator  and average, max, min the values. You could import the Excel sheet into an Access table and do that. I saw another somewhat similar question that might give you some ideas, if you're familiar with Access and SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226201/excel-vba-group-by-like-selection

Comment: I'm working with XL2010. And yes I suppose you could do it without VBA, but the background that I have not mentioned is how I'm actually really working with a bunch of chart making programs and a total of about a dozen other columns of information along with a few other sheets. However, all of this needs to be done multiple times in other files just as large as this, so I'm making a macro to complete everything I need so I can run it before I go to bed. What I ask above is just another piece to the puzzle I'm trying to complete.The formula would be nice as well,I'm sure I could adapt to VBA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Scott that in most cases, formulas are a better choice than VBA.  However you asked for some specific things, including sorting the data, presenting the results on a separate tab, so I will assume in this case you're OK with the extra overhead that comes with a macro.

You left out a few details regarding your data (data types, specific cell location, etc)... so see comments in the code, you may need to customize.

I tried to take your question as literally as possible... I may personally prefer the results in a table going down rather than across, for example, but that's not how I approached the answer.

```
Sub SummarizeDecade()

Const YearColumn As Integer = 2  'assumes the first year is in cell B2
Const FirstDataRow As Integer = 2 'assumes the first year is in cell B2

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet, wsNew As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rowStart As Long, rowEnd As Long, colPaste As Long
Dim decade As Integer
Dim avg As Double, mini As Double, maxi As Double 'you didn't specify data type, Double is most accommodating

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet  'assumes you run the macro while the data sheet is the current sheet; would prefer to use a sheet name

   'setup new worksheet for summary results, as requested
   wb.Worksheets.Add
   Set wsNew = wb.Worksheets(1)
   wsNew.Name = "Results"
   wsNew.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Decade"
   wsNew.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Average"
   wsNew.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Minimum"
   wsNew.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Maximum"
   colPaste = 2

   ws.Activate
   ws.Cells(FirstDataRow, YearColumn).Sort ws.Cells(FirstDataRow, YearColumn), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes 'sorts the data by year, as requested

   rowStart = FirstDataRow
   rowEnd = rowStart

   Do Until Len(ws.Cells(rowEnd, 3).Value) = 0 'be sure your data does not include strings with spaces, zeroes, etc.  Must be blank/null/empty.
      decade = Int(ws.Cells(rowStart, YearColumn) / 10) * 10

      Do Until Int(ws.Cells(rowEnd, YearColumn) / 10) * 10 <> decade
         rowEnd = rowEnd + 1
      Loop

      'calculate the average, max, and min
      avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowStart, 3), ws.Cells(rowEnd - 1, 3)))
      mini = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowStart, 3), ws.Cells(rowEnd - 1, 3)))
      maxi = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowStart, 3), ws.Cells(rowEnd - 1, 3)))

      'write the summaries on the new worksheet tab
      wsNew.Cells(1, colPaste).Value = decade
      wsNew.Cells(2, colPaste).Value = avg
      wsNew.Cells(3, colPaste).Value = mini
      wsNew.Cells(4, colPaste).Value = maxi

      colPaste = colPaste + 1
      rowStart = rowEnd
   Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers! You really hit the nail on the head there ExactaBox. Yes, I did leave some information out but you built the framework from which I can add on and customize, you have my sincere thanks, good work!

Comment: Glad I could help... I am new here, an "accepted" would be great.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Non-VBA solution:

See the picture below. I've taken the liberty of setting up the data in a neat format to display my concept, but you can easily adjust. Change the data range accordingly and the Max / Min formulas as well.

Make sure to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` as these formulas are array formulas.

[image: Non-VBA Solution]

Comment: This was one route I could have adapted to my own purpose, but not quite what I was looking for, I appreciate the help though! ExactaBox seemed to hit the nail on the head for this problem.